# Generate a JSON object form a the value of another JSON in WP8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I am working on a WP8 app. In this I need to connect to web services whose results will be some JSON. I was trying to extract some data from the result that the web service provide. I was able to extract from the initial JSON response. But I need to get some data from the value of one such key . SO I tried to generate another Json object from it.  But I m stuck. please help.Please find my example code below(I am using Newtonsoft.JSon).

```
private void messages_buttons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var str = "{'status': '0', 'result': '%7B%22campaign_id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22tfn%22%3A%2218773374136%22%2C%22campaign_code%22%3A%22PJC%22%2C%22ad_id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22qr_url%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F1d1.us%5C%2FPJC%5C%2F%22%2C%22campaign_name%22%3A%22PJ+Test+Campaign%22%2C%22is_active%22%3A%221%22%2C%22expire_on%22%3A%222021-05-05+00%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22start_on%22%3A%222021-05-05+00%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22alias%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icon_image_url%22%3A%22products%5C%2Fpjc%5C%2Fpjc3.jpg%22%2C%22fb_page_url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.facebook.com%5C%2FJackLaLannePowerJuicerssfb%22%2C%22video_url%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fyoutube.com%5C%2Fembed%5C%2FyZPedpRA9r0%3Fshowinfo%3D0%26autoplay%3D1%26loop%3D1%26playlist%3DyZPedpRA9r0%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.facebook.com'}";
            JObject ne = JObject.Parse(str);
            var x= (ne.GetValue("result")).ToString();
            var z = x.Replace("%", "");
            JObject newest = JObject.Parse(z);
            var y = newest.GetValue("campaign_id");
            MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());
        }
```

I get an exception at "JObject newest = JObject.Parse(z);" with the message
Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: m. Path '', line 1, position 6.
Am I doing it entirely wrong?

On a general note: can I convert a value from one Json to a another JSOn Itself? i.e if the value of one json  key is a string with some key value pairs, can i make a json object on that string?

Comment: @Gavin z will be string that have the string value of result without %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually just remove the % chars to get a valid value. You need to decode the string.

If you use this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x);
```

You'll find your "result" is actually invalid JSON:

> {"campaign_id":"1","tfn":"18773374136","campaign_code":"PJC","ad_id":"1","qr_url":"http://1d1.us/PJC/","campaign_name":"PJ
>   Test Campaign","is_active":"1","expire_on":"2021-05-05
>   00:00:00","start_on":"2021-05-05
>   00:00:00","alias":"","icon_image_url":"products/pjc/pjc3.jpg","fb_page_url":"https://www.facebook.com/JackLaLannePowerJuicerssfb","video_url":"http://youtube.com/embed/yZPedpRA9r0?showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=yZPedpRA9r0","url":"https://www.facebook.com

So hacking the value to make it valid JSON might work for you, by adding the missing "} at the end should turn your value in to valid JSON and allow you to parse it.

```
JObject newest = JObject.Parse(x + "\"}");
var y = newest.GetValue("campaign_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that `z` is a valid json object at this point. It is only the value of `result`. Try something like `JObject.Parse("'result':" + z);`

Comment: Thanks @earthling but all I want is to find some data from the string that was the value of 'result' key in the earlier jason

Comment: You're clearly getting the exception because the value isn't valid Jason. It looks like it could be valid Jason data, but you'd need to UrlDecode it first. See @Gavin's answer. Also, try validating it at jsonlint.com after you decode it if you are still getting an exception.